# Tkinter: why does the rectangle remain yellow while touched with the moving blue one?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a recipe named 'Detecting collisions between items' in 'Tkinter GUI Application Development Cookbook - 2018'.
The code runs perfectly as desired: You could move the bigger rectangle by pressing direction keys while the four smaller ones keep static near the corners. Once the bigger touchs any of the smaller ones, the latter will change into yellow from green. However, as there are two sequenced 'for' loops inside the 'precess_movements' circulation, I suppose the touched smaller rectangle should change its color frequently, which is against the observation while running. In order to verify my analysis is right, I placed 'print("item:" + str(item))' in the first loop to monitor the situation, and it turned out that in the first 'for' loop, all the four smaller rectangles turned back green when one of them collides with the bigger moving rectangle. This is obviously strange. Could anyone please shed light on this phenomenon? Thx
Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Detecting collisions between items")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.update()
        self.width = w = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.height = h = self.canvas.winfo_height()

        pos = (w / 2 - 15, h / 2 - 15, w / 2 + 15, h / 2 + 15)
        self.item = self.canvas.create_rectangle(*pos, fill="blue")
        positions = [(60, 60), (w - 60, 60), (60, h - 60), (w - 60, h - 60)]
        for x, y in positions:
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(x - 10, y - 10, x + 10, y + 10,
                                         fill="green")

        self.pressed_keys = {}
        self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.key_press)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.key_release)
        self.process_movements()

    def key_press(self, event):
        self.pressed_keys[event.keysym] = True

    def key_release(self, event):
        self.pressed_keys.pop(event.keysym, None)

    def process_movements(self):
        all_items = self.canvas.find_all()
        for item in filter(lambda i: i is not self.item, all_items):
            self.canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="green")
            print("item:" + str(item))  # monitoring items which have been turned green
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.canvas.coords(self.item)
        items = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x0, y0, x1, y1)
        for item in filter(lambda i: i is not self.item, items):
            self.canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="yellow")
        off_x, off_y = 0, 0
        speed = 3
        if 'Right' in self.pressed_keys:
            off_x += speed
        if 'Left' in self.pressed_keys:
            off_x -= speed
        if 'Down' in self.pressed_keys:
            off_y += speed
        if 'Up' in self.pressed_keys:
            off_y -= speed

        pos_x = x0 + (x1 - x0) / 2 + off_x
        pos_y = y0 + (y1 - y0) / 2 + off_y
        if 0 <= pos_x <= self.width and 0 <= pos_y <= self.height:
            self.canvas.move(self.item, off_x, off_y)

        self.after(100, self.process_movements)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: In the first for loop, you have set the fill color of the items to green.  So what you said strange is actually the normal result.

Comment: @acw1668 I think you misunderstand what I said. Color of the smaller rectangle hit by the bigger one should be green(1st for loop)-yellow(2nd for loop)-green(1st for loop)-yellow(2nd for loop)-green(1st for loop)-yellow(2nd for loop) and so on, if the latter keeps always overlapped with the former. However, it is not consistent with the running results observed. Why?

Comment: Although you have changed all the items to green in first for loop, but you change the overlapped item to yellow in the second for loop.  So you can only see overlapped item in yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have flashing effect on the overlapped item, i.e. green-yellow-green-yellow and so on, you only need the second for loop to find the overlapped item.  If an overlapped item is found, turn its fill color to yellow and schedule a task using `.after()` to turn its fill color back to green:

```
def process_movements(self):
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.canvas.coords(self.item)
    items = self.canvas.find_overlapping(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    for item in items:
        if item is not self.item:
            self.canvas.itemconfig(item, fill="yellow")
            # schedule a task 50ms later to reset fill color to green
            self.after(50, lambda i=item: self.canvas.itemconfig(i, fill="green"))

    off_x, off_y = 0, 0
    speed = 3
    if 'Right' in self.pressed_keys:
        off_x += speed
    if 'Left' in self.pressed_keys:
        off_x -= speed
    if 'Down' in self.pressed_keys:
        off_y += speed
    if 'Up' in self.pressed_keys:
        off_y -= speed

    pos_x = x0 + (x1 - x0) / 2 + off_x
    pos_y = y0 + (y1 - y0) / 2 + off_y
    if 0 <= pos_x <= self.width and 0 <= pos_y <= self.height:
        self.canvas.move(self.item, off_x, off_y)

    self.after(100, self.process_movements)
```